# Is there a keyboard shortcut for sleeping a display?

Tags: keyboard, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to put the display to sleep without putting the whole computer to sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/is-it-possible-to-put-the-display-to-sleep-without-putting-the-whole-computer-to)

What is the keyboard command to sleep (or turn off) a display, but not actually put the computer to sleep?

Comment: or of this: [Keyboard shortcut to turn off display not possible with MacBook Air](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/keyboard-shortcut-to-turn-off-display-not-possible-with-macbook-air/23928#23928)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard command for sleeping *all* displays is <kbd>Control ^</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>
 + <kbd>Eject ⏏</kbd>
. This shortcut doesn't put the computer to sleep, but only shuts off the display.

Comment: Doesn't work on the new MacBook Airs without an eject key.

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of sounding like a smart-ass, pressing the Power button on the display I wish to "sleep" works for me.

Comment: he means turning off the display whilst the computer is still awake. For example to allow a long download to run overnight without the annoyance of the screen saver or whatever.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that's what he meant, and my answer still stands.

Comment: @GarrettAlbright Internal displays don't have separate power buttons and if they're like my work external monitor can cause the Mac to rearrange all the windows to the internal display that you then sleep. If you don't want that to happen, Control-Shift-Eject is the only way.